# Why will Nginx not reroute all traffic to appropriate instance when "113: No route to host" error occurs?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have 2 back-end Ubuntu instances (BE1 & BE2) which both host separate Node servers and 1 front-end Ubuntu instance (FE1). I have configured Nginx on FE1 to load balance between the two Node servers using the following config:

```
    upstream backend {
      server x.x.x.1:3000;
      server x.x.x.2:3000;
    }        

    location /api {
      rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
```

When I stop one of the Node servers, Nginx reroutes all traffic to the other one as expected. However, if I shut down either instance BE1 or BE2 completely I see `[error] 1109#1109: *456 connect() failed (113: No route to host)`  in the FE error logs and Nginx continues to send traffic to both back-end servers as if nothing happened. How can I make Nginx reroute traffic when one of these instances goes down?